# What is the tf threading model?

Tags: ros, geometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use it in a single threaded node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9483/what-is-the-tf-threading-model?/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [TransformListener](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html) class is continuously listening for incoming coordinate transforms from [TransformBroadcaster](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformBroadcaster.html)s. Any blocking call would severely disrupt the flow of information to the listener. Therefore,
a transform listener, by default, spins its own thread. This particularly helps with calls to functions like `tf::Transformer::waitForTransform` which can block callbacks while it is waiting to hear back from tf.

- The API for `tf::Transformer`, `tf::TransformListener` and `tf::TransformSender` all use mutex locks to be threadsafe.
- `tf::Transformer::waitForTransform` requires a dedicated listening thread (provided by default by [tf::TransformListener](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html))

If TransformListener spins a thread it will only service callbacks in the custom callback queue for the tf topic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2013-12-09**:
I would love it if info like the answer here (especially the bullet points) were put into the doxygen comments for tf::TransformListener (and sender etc).